# Font Awesome with pdfbox and boxable

Tags: java, font-awesome, pdfbox

I'm trying to use the font awesome from bootstrap to use it's icons.

my code is like:

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = addNewPage(doc);
PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc,new File("D:/workspace/pdfbox/PDF/src/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"));
//Create Header row
Row<PDPage> headerRow = table.createRow(15f);
Cell<PDPage> cell = headerRow.createCell(100, "\uf05e");
cell.setFont(font);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+F05E is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.encode(PDTrueTypeFont.java:368)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:286)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getStringWidth(PDFont.java:315)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Paragraph.getLines(Paragraph.java:83)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Paragraph.getHeight(Paragraph.java:154)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Cell.getTextHeight(Cell.java:391)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Cell.getCellHeight(Cell.java:366)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Row.getHeight(Row.java:159)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Table.getMinimumHeight(Table.java:697)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.Table.draw(Table.java:192)
    at TableTest.main(TableTest.java:58)
```

I know that "\uf05e" is valid in this font.

Does someone konw where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please load the font with

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc,new File("D:/workspace/pdfbox/PDF/src/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"));
```

this allows the use of others than just the usual standard characters. This is only available in PDFBox 2.0 and higher.